# Only a certain Pattern of Geometry data is being rendered on Canvas in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, geometry

I am trying to Display some Geometry Resources in a Canvas
I have Placed the required data inside a canvas and I noticed that only a certain type of data is being rendered in the View (path with negative values do not get rendered) .

Any Idea why I might be facing this problem and any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Canvas does not resize its child elements, hence the coordinates of your Paths are used as-is. Obviously the coordinates of the FolderIcon Path are far outside any visible region of your application.

Instead of using a Canvas, you may want to directly use the Path elements as resources. Then also make them stretch automatically by setting `Stretch="Uniform"`, and take care that they can be re-used multiple times by setting `x:Shared="False"`.

```
<Path x:Key="FileIcon" x:Shared="False" Width="12" Height="12"
      Stretch="Uniform" Stroke="Black" x:Shared="False" Fill="White" Data="..."/>
<Path x:Key="FolderIcon" x:Shared="False" Width="12" Height="12"
      Stretch="Uniform" Stroke="Black" Fill="White" Data="..."/>
```